# How to redirect input to the Shell?

Tags: spring-cloud-dataflow

I've tried `java -jar shell.jar < commands.txt` but that doesn't seem to work.
One would think a shell would support redirection for use in scripts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a `--spring.shell.commandFile` option that's [supported](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-dataflow/blob/master/spring-cloud-dataflow-shell/src/main/java/org/springframework/cloud/dataflow/shell/ShellProperties.java#L39) at the Shell app, but it is not documented - we will fix it.

With that, you could pass the commands like:

`java -jar shell.jar --spring.shell.commandFile="commands.txt"`